# How to kill .animate() after the user hovers off?

Tags: jquery

Code:

```
//create the animation.
  $('img#header').hover(function(){
  $(this).animate({"top": "-10px" }, "slow");
```

I am trying to have the hover stop and go back to normal when the user hovers off the image. I got the animation working, just not when I hover off. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('img#header').hover(function()
{
    $(this).animate({"top": "-10px" }, "slow");
}, function()
{
    $(this).animate({"top": "0"}, "slow");
});
```

Comment: +1 - I would also add a `.stop()` before each `.animate()` call, to prevent a queue when hovering in/out.

Comment: Sorry but "didn't work" isn't a useful error message. What errors messages are output (in Firefox/Chrome's console)?